# Drag and Drop Files in Unity with 3 Monitors

Tags: unity, 12.04, nvidia, drag-and-drop, xinerama

I have been experiencing an odd phenomenon in Ubuntu Unity (2D and 3D) with 11.04/11.10 and 12.04.

I have three monitors running on nVidia gpus (in Ubuntu 12.04, this configured itself with the restricted drivers and Xinerama), and when I select a file (or group of files) from a window, although the mouse continues to hover where I begin to drag, the icons of the dragged file(s) appear one screen to the left.  This would be a non-issue if releasing them didn't move them to where ever they are hovering.

It's like Ubuntu is confused altogether which screen I am dragging from, since the positions correspond to the same location on a different monitor.

I pondered this a couple times in the past but haven't been able to google myself an answer (as I apparently can't describe this problem adequately to search), and now I have a fresh 12.04 (x64) install where this is again happening.

Thanks for your consideration in advance.

Comment: This might be an associated problem, although I'm only experiencing this now in 12.04 (x64) and not previously in the 11.04/11.10 versions: The cursor, when moving from the left most monitor (monitor 1) to the next monitor over instead jumps to the right most monitor (monitor 3).  However, when moving the mouse left, it goes to the correct monitor when it hits the monitor edge limit.  That is to say, if I start at the left most monitor and move my mouse right, there is no way to arrive at the middle monitor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had similar problems with a 3 monitor (2 NVidia GPUs) setup using 10.04 (x64) and was able to work around the issue by physically connecting my monitors in a different order to the cards.  Even though the nvidia-settings tool allowed me to change the order of the displays, I'd get strange problems if I varied the default order that shows up initially.

Hope this helps

Comment: Your answer was spot on (and Thank You for that. :) ).  As it turns out, the nvidia driver appears to have issues with identifying the monitors if their order isn't sequential.  It wasn't until I reorganized the monitors such that DFP-0 on GPU-0 was followed by DFP-1 on GPU-0 which was then followed by DFP-0 on GPU-1 (or monitors 0, 1 and 2 in that order) that BOTH issues were resolved.  For anyone else having similar difficulties, try setting up the xorg.conf with the nvidia x server settings with the monitors sequentially as HopeThisHelps recommended.